# How to toggling the visibility of a class on the hover of a list item?

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

I am trying to toggle the visibility of ".image1" when I hover over ".block1" but Im not having any success. What am I missing? Can anyone help me out?

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="wrapper">

            <section class="images">

                <article id="image" class="image1">
                    <div class="img"></div>
                </article>

                <article id="image" class="image2">
                    <div class="img"></div>
                </article>

                <article id="image" class="image3">
                    <div class="img"></div>
                </article>

            </section>
            <ul class="blocks">

                <li class="block1">Image1
                </li>
                <li class="block2">Image2
                </li>
                <li class="block3">Image3
                </li>

            </ul>

        </div>    
    </div>
```

SCRIPT:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".block1").hover(function(){
    $(".image1").fadeTo("slow", 1);
    },function(){
        $(".image1").fadeTo("slow", 0);
});
});
```

Here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lm3Z4/3/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you forgot to choose the jQuery framework on jsfiddle. Add jQuery library before you use it in your page.

To add library file within your website in js folder on root

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jQuery.min.js"></script>
```

To Add library from [googleapis](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery)

```
<script src="http//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Lm3Z4/4/)**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".block1").hover(function(){
        $(".image1").fadeTo("slow", 1);
        },function(){
            $(".image1").fadeTo("slow", 0);
    });
});
```

Comment: Haha thank you! for some reason its still not working locally. its driving me crazy.

Comment: Did you added jQuery file locally?

Comment: You forgot to load library file in Jsfiddle

Here is Updated link 



  [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/Lm3Z4/13/

Comment: I didn't close a script tag. :/

Comment: Works great now haha! Thank you both for your help!